# BigQuery Merge and Sum JSON Documents

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I want to merge JSON string in a table and sum its value after group
for Eg:-

`2023, {"hen":4, "owl":3}`
`2023, {"crow":4, "owl":2}`
`2022, {"owl":6, "crow":2}`
`2022, {"hen":5}`
`2021, {"hen":2, "crow":1}`

Result could be like below

`2023, {"hen":4, "owl":5, "crow":4}`
`2022, {"hen":5, "owl":6, "crow":2}`
`2021, {"hen":2, "crow":1}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

below might be an option when you don't know json object keys beforehand.

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT 2023 year, '{"hen":4, "owl":3}' json UNION ALL
  SELECT 2023, '{"crow":4, "owl":2}' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2022, '{"owl":6, "crow":2}' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2022, '{"hen":5}' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2021, '{"hen":2, "crow":1}'
)
SELECT year, '{' || STRING_AGG(k || ':' || v, ', ') || '}' json FROM (
  SELECT year, 
         SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)] k, 
         SUM(SAFE_CAST(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(1)] AS INT64)) v
    FROM sample_table, UNNEST(SPLIT(TRIM(json, '{}'), ', ')) kv
   GROUP BY 1, 2
) GROUP BY 1;
```

**Query results**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Consider also below approach

```
create temp function get_keys(input string) returns array<string> language js as """
  return Object.keys(JSON.parse(input));
  """;
create temp function get_values(input string) returns array<string> language js as """ 
  return Object.values(JSON.parse(input));
  """;
select distinct year, 
  '{' || string_agg(format('"%s":%i', key ,sum(cast(val as int64))), ', ') over(partition by year) || '}' json
from your_table, unnest(get_keys(json)) key with offset
join unnest(get_values(json)) val with offset
using (offset)
group by year, key
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]